# aplicativo crasha ao entrar em modo Landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Meu app tem dois layouts, um pro modo portrait e outro pro landscape. Ao atribuir um evento para abrir outra activity ao botão da tela, quando giro o celular, (coloco-o em modo landscape) o app crasha.Se não girar o dispositivo, tudo acontece normalmente. Qual poderia ser o motivo disso?

código da activity que crasha
    package com.example.igor.olddog;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_calcular_idade;
EditText idade_cachorro;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_calcular_idade = findViewById(R.id.btn_calcular_idade);
    idade_cachorro = findViewById(R.id.edit_caixa_texto);


    btn_calcular_idade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent abrir_resultadoActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultadoActivity.class);
            startActivity(abrir_resultadoActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

O problema era que no xml do modo landscape o btn estava com um ID diferente do que estava no modo portrait